# Why is the ng-click inserted records twice sometimes in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I've got a Submit button that's used to insert item:

```html
<div class="col-md-12"> 
    <div class="form-body">
    <div class="form-group pull-right"> 
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">&nbsp;</label>                         `
    <button type="button" id="subbtn" class="btn btn-success margin-t12" ng-click="Submit();">Submit</button> //button
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default margin-t12" ng-click="back();">Cancel</button>                              </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Now when I press the Submit button I noticed sometime the item inserted twice with same details.  I applied below solution already but the issue not resolved yet.

```js
    $('#subbtn').attr("disabled", 'disabled'); //button disable
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#subbtn').removeAttr("disabled")
    }, 10000);
```

I'm just wondering what I've overlooked...

Comment: Probably you click twice on the button and this is the reason item is inserted twice. Although you set attribute disabled on button after click, this does not disable button immediately, but on the next angular scope digest cycle.

Comment: Is there any solution for it.

Comment: You should control inside your code if previous save is not finished yet. For example you could setup variable saveInProgress=true in the submit function and set it to false when insert is finished. Then you add check at the beginning of submit function, that checks if SaveInProgress==true. In case is true you exit the function immediately.